# Json parsing accent characters

Tags: java, json

The issue I am facing is that when I parse a character with an accent, my program will spit out random gibberish for that character. Is there any way I can parse the characters such that it will it parse out and accent character instead?

Parsing `Céline Dion` => `CÃ©line Dion`

```
String fullURLPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + songInfoQuery.replace(" ", "+");

        System.out.println("!" + fullURLPath.toString());

        URL url = new URL(fullURLPath);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();

        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray arr = rootobj.getAsJsonArray("results");
        try {
            rootobj = arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("not in itunes");
        }
```

Comment: Don't use exception handling to check the "not in itunes" case. Aside from the fact it's not actually an exceptional case, you don't know if the IOOBE occurs as a result of `arr.get(0)` or something occurring in `getAsJsonObject()`. Check the length of the array.

Comment: Right I was just using that as an error checking method for testing, I will be sure to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are parsing the data being sent back to you using your JVM's default charset, which is different from the charset used to encode the response.

Looking at the response headers from getting that URL in my browser, the response is sent as UTF-8.

You should explicitly specify the charset when you create your `InputStreamReader`:

```
new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

You could alternatively specify UTF-8 as your default charset when starting your JVM, but it is easy to forget to do that - it is better to be explicit in your code.

Comment: I have a hunch that it is due to the character set but this did not change anything, unfortunately

Comment: @QQPrinti it is definitely to do with charsets. `"Ã©"` is what you get if you interpret the UTF-8 bytes for `"é"` as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: You're right, I am too embarrassed to say what I was doing but you've nailed it! Thank you